# Enumeration with all elements of given Enumeration and intermitted other elements in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a function `f()` and an `IEnumerable<string>` from which I want to create another `IEnumerable<string>` so that for each string `s` in the original enumeration the new one has `s` and `f(s)`. The order of elements is important.

Example:

```
IEnumerable<string> given  = { "A",         "B",         "C"         };
IEnumerable<string> wanted = { "A", f("A"), "B", f("B"), "C", f("C") };
```

Is there a way to do this *elegantly* using LINQ? (And if not, what's the most elegant way to do this?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var wanted = given.SelectMany(s => new[] {s, f(s)} );
```

[`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) projects each element of a sequence to another *sequence* and then *flattens* the resulting sequence of sequences into a single sequence.

In query syntax:

```
var wanted = from s in given
             from item in new[] {s, f(s)}
             select item;
```

Another alternative (if ordering were not important):

```
var wanted = given.Concat(given.Select(f)); // C# 4
var wanted = given.Concat(given.Select(s => f(s)));  // C# 3
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> AddFuncCall(this IEnumerable<string> input)
{
  foreach (string s in input)
  {
    yield return s;
    yield return "f(" + s + ")";
  }
}
```

If you need the quotes embedded in the strings, try this (not 100% sure on syntax):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> AddFuncCall(this IEnumerable<string> input)
{
  foreach (string s in input)
  {
    yield return @""" + s + @""";
    yield return @"f("" + s + @"")";
  }
}

IEnumerable<string> given  = { "A", "B", "C"}; 
IEnumerable<string> wanted = given.AddFuncCall();
```

[EDIT]
Sorry, I misread the question, I thought you wanted strings like "f("A")" in the output as opposed to executing `f` on each string from the input.  Whoops!

Comment: It's not `"f(A)"`, but `f("A")`. (Or am I missing something?) Anyway, writing a method for this doesn't seem very elegant to me.

Comment: +1: This is fine; this is a good way to do it in C# 2, other than the extension method of course. (I don't think the slight question misread is all that important here)

Comment: @Ani: I didn't consider the misread all that important, I just wanted to rule out that I was missing something. Still, I find your `from s in given from item in new[] {s, f(s)} select item;` considerably simpler to read and understand (aka "more elegant") than writing a special method for this.

Comment: @sbi: I completely agree; after C# 3, writing iterator blocks has become a rare occurrence, for me at least. But I think this is good for others who read this question, especially those still on C# 2, to see how you can get 'easy' deferred execution queries without LINQ.